# interpreting meta-regression outputs from metafor

Tags: r, statistics, metafor

I have been using the *metafor* package for some meta-analyses and would like to adjust for a single continuous covariate (mean age) using meta-regression. However, I require some clarification regarding the outputs and what they mean. Below I have shared the output for the base case analysis as well as the meta-regression (same studies in both, with the only difference being the addition of covariates for the meta-regression).

Base case output

```
Random-Effects Model (k = 36; tau^2 estimator: DL)

  logLik  deviance       AIC       BIC      AICc  
-18.8613   60.5927   41.7226   44.8896   42.0862  

tau^2 (estimated amount of total heterogeneity): 0.0633 (SE = 0.0327)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):      0.2515
I^2 (total heterogeneity / total variability):   51.46%
H^2 (total variability / sampling variability):  2.06

Test for Heterogeneity: 
Q(df = 35) = 72.1031, p-val = 0.0002

Model Results:

estimate       se     zval     pval    ci.lb    ci.ub          
  0.1266   0.0633   2.0014   0.0453   0.0026   0.2506        * 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Meta-regression (output)

```
Mixed-Effects Model (k = 36; tau^2 estimator: DL)

  logLik  deviance       AIC       BIC      AICc  
-18.7696   60.4092   43.5391   48.2897   44.2891  

tau^2 (estimated amount of residual heterogeneity):     0.0677 (SE = 0.0346)
tau (square root of estimated tau^2 value):             0.2601
I^2 (residual heterogeneity / unaccounted variability): 52.84%
H^2 (unaccounted variability / sampling variability):   2.12
R^2 (amount of heterogeneity accounted for):            0.00%

Test for Residual Heterogeneity: 
QE(df = 34) = 72.1024, p-val = 0.0001

Test of Moderators (coefficient(s) 2): 
QM(df = 1) = 0.2456, p-val = 0.6202

Model Results:

         estimate      se     zval    pval    ci.lb   ci.ub   
intrcpt   -0.3741  1.0140  -0.3690  0.7122  -2.3616  1.6133   
mods       0.0085  0.0172   0.4955  0.6202  -0.0252  0.0423   

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

My questions are:

1. Why are we observing an R-squared of 0% in the meta-regression (is it simply because the covariate is not significant or do you suspect something is not correct)?
2. How can we interpret the outputs of the meta-regression? With back-transformation of the logHRs we suspect something like below, but would like to make sure that I am interpreting the ‘intrcpt’ and ‘mods’ values correctly.

   - I have assumed mods represents the pooled HR taking into account the adjustment for age.
   - I have assumed intrcpt represents the covariate effect (beta) – i.e. the amount that the logHR changes for a one unit increase in age. Also, I have back-transformed this output, which I am not sure is appropriate, or if I should present as is.

Comment: Interpreting the results of statistical models really isn't a programming question. If you have questions about statistical models, you should ask over at [stats.se], not here.

Comment: I might have not read the terms correctly. Apologies for that.

Comment: You might want to ask this on the R-sig-meta-analysis mailing list at: https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis